# Regex giving different results for English and Russian

Tags: python, regex, pyre2

So, I have this regular expression:

```
[ ]{1}[^\w]*(шесть)[^\w]*[ ]{1}
```

And a variation of it:

```
[ ]{1}[^\w]*(conservation)[^\w]*[ ]{1}
```

I use this text, [here](http://regexr.com/), to test it:

> """Наверное, по одному на пару отделений, а их больше десяти.
>   Интересно, каждый работает по шесть часов в неделю? Работать,
>   очевидно, некому, раз принимают сами заведующие. Но неужели экономия
>   на нескольких диагностах"""
>
> """Following the assassination of President McKinley in September
>   1901, Roosevelt, at age 42, became the youngest United States
>   President in history. Leading his party and country into the
>   Progressive Era, he championed his "Square Deal" domestic policies,
>   promising the average citizen fairness, breaking of trusts, regulation
>   of railroads, and pure food and drugs. Making conservation a top
>   priority, he established myriad new шесть national parks, forests, and
>   monuments intended to preserve the nation's natural resources. In
>   foreign policy, he focused on Central America, where he began
>   construction of the Panama Canal. He greatly expanded the United
>   States Navy, and sent the Great White Fleet on a world tour to project
>   the United States' naval power around the globe. His successful
>   efforts to end the Russo-Japanese War won him the 1906 Nobel Peace
>   Prize."""

Both are just random texts I found. But this is besides the point.

When using the first regex, I get the following matches:

> по одному на пару отделений, а их больше десяти. Интересно, каждый
>   работает по шесть часов в неделю? Работать, очевидно, некому, раз
>   принимают сами заведующие. Но неужели экономия на нескольких

This is in the first block of text, the Russian one.

In the second one, it only matches

> шесть

The context of the match is

> ... new шесть national parks ...

If I use an English word, like "conservation" it only matches the word in the English block of text.

If I add it to the Russian text, something like:

> ... шесть conservation часов ...

It matches the same large chunk of text like "шесть".

Why is this happening? Is it because the text is in Russian?

I'm not one hundred percent sure what this regex does, but in English texts it finds the word in parenthesis. I assumed it does the same for other languages.

It doesn't really matter but fyi I'm using the re2 library with Python 2.7. However, since I'm getting the same result online, I'm assuming it's either something with the regex that I don't understand or some problem with non English texts.

Thanks!

**EDIT 1:**

The code:

```
source = the_text_above
term = "шесть"
expression = regex_builder(term) # This returns the regex I posted
compiled_pattern = re2.compile(expression, re2.IGNORECASE, re2.U) # This raises an error: RegexError: pattern too large - compile failed
compiled_pattern.search(source).span() # This returns the start and end of the chunk of text I mentioned.
```

Addendum to EDIT 1: The chunk of text is returned when I don't use re2.U

**EDIT 2:**

I also tried with:

```
compiled_pattern = re.compile(expression, re.U)
```

I get the same result.

**EDIT 3 - SOLVED:**

So, I tried to compile again with both re2.IGNORECASE and re2.U flags and it worked.

Now my code looks like this:

```
source = the_text_above
term = "шесть"
expression = regex_builder(term)
compiled_pattern = re2.compile(expression, re2.IGNORECASE | re2.U)
compiled_pattern.search(source).span()
```

It works like this.

Comment: Please write your python code. How you're using the regex and how are you displaying the output?

Comment: If you use a `re.U` flag, `\w` will match Russian letters and `\W` (= your `[^\w]`) will stop matching Cyrillic letters. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/yR3uY0/1)

Comment: I added the flag, but now I get this error: RegexError: pattern too large - compile failed --- I am using re2, I will also try with regular re.

Comment: Please try `[ ][^\pL\pN_]*(шесть)[^\pL\pN_]*[ ]` with re2

Comment: @stribizhev I tried this, but to no avail. It still returns a large chunk of text around the word.

Comment: what is `regex_builder` function?

Comment: @tglaria It's a function that returns the pattern [ ]{1}[^\w]*(term)[^\w]*[ ]{1}

Comment: [*In Perl mode, RE2 accepts most Perl operators.*](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/CplusplusAPI) - is the one you are using in Perl mode?

Comment: @stribizhev No, you were right at first, it was the re2.U flag. The problem was I was doing re2.compile( ..., re2.I , re2.U) instead of re2.compile(..., re2.I | re2.U ) this was causing an error so there was no effect from the re2.U.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In RE2, `\w` only matches ASCII letters if you do not specify the `re2.U` flag:

> `\w`  word characters (≡ `[0-9A-Za-z_]`)

And thus `[^\w]` matches Cyrillic letters.

So, you need to use the `re2.U` flag.

Since you combine a `re2.I` with `re2.U`, you need to use a bitwise OR (`|`) in-between:

```
re2.compile(<YOUR_PATTERN>, re2.I | re2.U)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having no error using Python 2.7.10 and `re` module:

```
import re
txt_ru = u"""Наверное, по одному на пару отделений, а их больше десяти. Интересно, каждый работает по шесть часов в неделю? Работать, очевидно, некому, раз принимают сами заведующие. Но неужели экономия на нескольких диагностах"""
txt_en = u"""regulation of railroads, and pure food and drugs. Making conservation a top priority, he established myriad new шесть national parks, forests,"""
expression = u"[ ]{1}[^\w]*(шесть)[^\w]*[ ]{1}"
m_ru = re.search(expression, txt_ru, re.UNICODE)
m_en = re.search(expression, txt_en, re.UNICODE)
```

Output:

```
In [166]: print m_ru.group(0)
 шесть 

In [167]: print m_en.group(0)
 шесть
```

Comment: Yes, with `re`, you need to use `re.U` or `re.UNICODE` to make `\w` match Unicode letters. However, OP uses RE2 library, and the issue was in the combination of 2 flags.